# does installing Flask python package within PyCharm create duplicate entries on my hard drive?

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

This is basically a question on how **Install** really works with Pip and Python, i.e. what physically happens when you "Install a package"

I assume when I use pip to install flask from my terminal window on MacOS... that some s/w is being downloaded from the internet and physically installed somewhere in the python tree of folders. in other words, I'm permanently using HD space

now I'm starting to use Pycharm and it doesn't recognize flask... I can use the Python Packages Window to "**ADD**" the package... will that download again the same code I already have installed on my HD (when I ran pip in terminal window) or will it be smart enough to **point to** flask that is already there?

Comment: Where are you specifically adding the package?

Comment: hi. very strange. i assume the place to add it is in the python package window within the pyCharm console..but when i click on 'add package' there, it gives 2 options:  from disk, from version control....  but I want to add from PyPI dont I
    I was able to click on the error in the main window ( I refer to the error when i tried to run my script which starts with "from flask import Flask"), it allowed me to execute the pip -m install flask ... i think it was a pop up window that allowed this.

Comment: And which option are you choosing? I don't know what you mean by "but I want to add from PyPI dont I". This question is missing details.